# Cannot get user email with facebook integration

Tags: javascript, facebook

I'm trying to get the user's email after they press Continue with Facebook on my site. I've looked on Stackoverflow and through the Facebook Developer documentation and cannot see a reason why what I am trying isn't working.

**JAVASCRIPT**

```
window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
  FB.init({
    appId      : '1882306058687148',
    cookie     : true,
    xfbml      : true,
    version    : 'v2.8'
  });
  FB.AppEvents.logPageView();
  FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
    statusChangeCallback(response);
  });
};

(function(d, s, id){
  var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
  if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
  js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
  js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js";
  fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));

function checkLoginState() {
  FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
    console.log(response);
    statusChangeCallback(response)
  });
}

function statusChangeCallback(response) {
  console.log('statusChangeCallback');
  console.log(response);
  if (response.status === 'connected') {
    runAPI();
  }
}

function runAPI() {
  FB.api('/me', { locale: 'en_US', fields: 'name, email' }, function(response) {
    console.log(response);
    document.getElementById('name').value = response.name;
    document.getElementById('email').value = response.email;
    document.getElementById('fb-login').style.display = 'none'
  });
}
```

** HTML **

```
<fb:login-button scope="public_profile,email" onlogin="checkLoginState();">
</fb:login-button>
```

What's confusing me the most though is that this **IS** pulling the name through and that is definitely working.

Comment: You will only get an email address back if the user has a verified one set in their profile. And even then, there are apparently some edge cases where privacy settings can still make it not return one at all. Of course, they might not have one set at all, if they registered using only their mobile. If your app _needs_ and email address, then you should implement an additional step for users to input one manually. (Verification is your responsibility as well in that case.)

Comment: From [this link](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/permissions#reference-email),     `Note, even if you request the email permission it is not guaranteed you will get an email address. For example, if someone signed up for Facebook with a phone number instead of an email address, the email field may be empty.`  Did you try with multiple accounts? If not, it could be the reason why it's not working

Comment: This is currently being tested with the new facebook account I set up using the email - thats good to know though so thank you.

Comment: @CBroe - sorry I was wrong!! I thought I had verified the email, but apparently I only verified the email. If you answer with your comment I'll mark as best! Thanks!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will only get an email address back if the user has a verified one set in their profile.

---

And even then, there are apparently some edge cases where privacy settings can still make it not return one at all. Of course, they might not have one set at all, if they registered using only their mobile. If your app needs and email address, then you should implement an additional step for users to input one manually. (Verification is your responsibility as well in that case.)

Comment: Cheers for this really helped me.